# Select nodes in T-SQL XML by name given in a variable

Tags: xml, t-sql

I'm trying to select nodes in XML document by provided name.

```sql
declare @xdoc xml = '

    <data>
        <box><id>1</id><weight>10</weight></box>
        <tube><id>2</id><weight>20</weight></tube> <!-- Should be skipped -->
        <box><id>3</id><weight>30</weight></box>
    </data>

'

declare @node nvarchar(100)='box'

select
    ref.value('id[1]','bigint') as Id,
    ref.value('weight[1]','bigint') as Weight
from @xdoc.nodes('/data/*[local-name()=[sql:variable("@node")]]') as xdata(ref)
-- WORKS FINE:from @xdoc.nodes('/data/*[local-name()="box"]') as xdata(ref)
```

and it gives me error message:

```
XQuery [nodes()]: Syntax error near '[', expected a step expression.
```

How do I access local variable in xml.nodes()? Or may be there is some better way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath expression misses a `*` around `/data/` and has some superfluous `[]` around `sql:variable("@node")`:
it should be

```
select
  ref.value('id[1]','bigint') as Id,
  ref.value('weight[1]','bigint') as Weight
from @xdoc.nodes('/data/*[local-name()=sql:variable("@node")]') as xdata(ref)
```

EDIT: added correction mentioned in comment by author.

Comment: Ah, copypaste is not my friend :)  Correct full query looks like `/data/*[local-name()=sql:variable("@node")]`

Comment: @dmay: Yes, You're expression makes more sense. I hope you don't mind if I put it in the answer for future reference.