# Cannot pass variable to sql:variable() function within xml.Nodes() in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I'm trying to pass in a value to xml.nodes so that I can genericize:

```
DECLARE @xml xml = 
'
<root>
    <level1>
        <sublevel1>
            <val>this is a value</val>
            <val>this is also a value</val>
        </sublevel1>
    </level1>
</root>
'

declare @xmlPath nvarchar(250) = '/root/level1/sublevel1'

Select @xmlPath as [path], t.c.query('.') as data
from @xml.nodes ('/root/level1/sublevel1') as t(c)  --this line find the nodes
--from @xml.nodes ('*[local-name()=sql:variable("@xmlPath")]') as t(c)  --This one doesn't
```

I got to this possible solution when I tried to pass in a variable `.Nodes(@xmlPath)` or  concatenate the path and the Nodes() function required a string literal.

Expected result:
[image]

```
<sublevel1>
  <val>this is a value</val>
  <val>this is also a value</val>
</sublevel1>
```

I'm getting no error, but also no data returned when I run this.

References for this method:

https://codegumbo.com/index.php/2013/10/04/sql-server-xquery-functions-sqlvariable-sqlcolumn/

[Get SQL xml attribute value using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9231411/get-sql-xml-attribute-value-using-variable)

[Select nodes in T-SQL XML by name given in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48694052/select-nodes-in-t-sql-xml-by-name-given-in-a-variable)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-extension-functions-sql-variable?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Don't think you can do dynamic node matching this way

Comment: Can you limit it to a particular level? Or a fixed number of possible levels?

Comment: @Charlieface Possibly, I'm not sure what that would look like.

Comment: Ie can you split up the paths into (a maximum of) a fixed number of nodes `@xmlPath1` `@xmlPath2` `@xmlPath3` or do you need to have aribitrary depth?

Comment: I don't think a fixed number of nodes will work.  Although I suppose if you have an example I could try it.

Comment: @lptr, add this as an answer. openxml, as usual, is the king of xml operations in sql server

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do dynamic node descent. Each variable is only compared against a single node's name.

If you have a fixed number of nodes to descend then you can just query each level independently.

```sql
Select
  t.c.query('.') as data
from @xml.nodes('
  *[local-name()=sql:variable("@xmlPath1")]
  /*[local-name()=sql:variable("@xmlPath2")]
  /*[local-name()=sql:variable("@xmlPath3")]
') as t(c);
```

If you have a dynamic, but maximum, number of nodes to descend then you can use some nested `if` and `for` expressions

```sql
Select
  t.c.query('.') as data
from @xml.nodes('
  for $n1 in *[local-name()=sql:variable("@xmlPath1")]
  return
    if (sql:variable("@xmlPath2") > "")
    then
      for $n2 in $n1/*[local-name()=sql:variable("@xmlPath2")]
      return
        if (sql:variable("@xmlPath3") > "")
        then
          $n2/*[local-name()=sql:variable("@xmlPath3")]
        else $n2
    else $n1
') as t(c);
```

You can nest it as deep as you want, but it's likely to be pretty inefficient. XQuery in SQL Server is designed to have a fixed path to query, not to use dynamic matching.

Getting the full path is going to be even more complex, and probably impossible with this design.

---

Another option is to use multiple levels of `OUTER APPLY nodes` to get the correct results. This allows you to get the path as well, using `CONCAT_WS` to combine the node names with a separator.

```sql
Select
  concat_ws('/',
    t1.c.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(100)'),
    t2.c.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(100)'),
    t3.c.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(100)')
  ) as path,
  case when @xmlPath3 is not null
       then t3.c.query('.')
       when @xmlPath2 is not null
       then t2.c.query('.')
       else
            t1.c.query('.')
  end as data
from        @xml.nodes('*[local-name()=sql:variable("@xmlPath1")]') t1(c)
outer apply t1.c.nodes('*[local-name()=sql:variable("@xmlPath2")]') t2(c)
outer apply t2.c.nodes('*[local-name()=sql:variable("@xmlPath3")]') t3(c);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/U9-IsZmD)

Answer (score 1):

you can use dynamic sql to solve problem

```
DECLARE @xml xml = 
'
<root>
    <level1>
        <sublevel1>
            <val>this is a value</val>
            <val>this is also a value</val>
        </sublevel1>
    </level1>
</root>
'

declare @xmlPath nvarchar(250) = '/root/level1/sublevel1'

declare @SQL nvarchar(max)
set @SQL = 'select '''+@xmlPath+''' as [path], t.c.query(''.'') as dataa
from  @xml.nodes('''+@xmlPath+''') as t(c)'
exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@xml xml', @xml
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BvuDQNhy)

Comment: Not injection safe, but I suppose it works

Comment: I don't want to use this because its production code.  Although no user entry is directly involved, so its probably ok...

Comment: I did not understand the problem. You don't want to use it because it is dynamic